# subtract specific row und rename it

Tags: r, dataframe, row, subset, subtraction

it is possible to subtract certain rows and rename them?

```
year <- c(2005,2005,2005,2006,2006,2006,2007,2007,2007)
category <- c("a","b","c","a","b","c", "a", "b", "c")
value <- c(2,2,10,3,3,12,4,4,16)
df <- data.frame(year, category,value, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

And this is how the result should look:

| year | category | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2005 | a | 2 |
| 2005 | b | 2 |
| 2005 | c | 4 |
| 2006 | a | 3 |
| 2006 | b | 3 |
| 2006 | c | 12 |
| 2007 | a | 4 |
| 2007 | b | 4 |
| 2007 | c | 16 |
| **2005** | **c-b** | **2** |
| **2006** | **c-b** | **9** |
| **2007** | **c-b** | **12** |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `group_modify`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  group_by(year) %>% 
  group_modify(~ add_row(.x, category = "c-b", value = .x$value[.x$category == "c"] - .x$value[.x$category == "b"]))

# A tibble: 12 x 3
# Groups:   year [3]
    year category value
   <dbl> <chr>    <dbl>
 1  2005 a            2
 2  2005 b            2
 3  2005 c           10
 4  2005 c-b          8
 5  2006 a            3
 6  2006 b            3
 7  2006 c           12
 8  2006 c-b          9
 9  2007 a            4
10  2007 b            4
11  2007 c           16
12  2007 c-b         12
```

Answer (score 0):

See `substract()` function.

Example:

```
substracted_df<-substr(df,df$category=="c")
```

If you want to know which rows are you dealing with, use `which()`

```
rows<-which(df$category=="c")
substracted_df<-df[rows, ]
```

You can rename each desired row as

```
row.names(substracted_df)<-c("Your desired row names")
```